# How to find chromebook by dns name?

Tags: chromebook

If I have a chromebook on my network, can I find it by computer name (rather than having to know the IP) like I can with Windows PC's (which register their DNS name with the router when getting an IP via DHCP)?

I do notice the chromebook doesn't seem to send a machine name to the router, since the router shows "*" as the machine name with the chromebook's IP

Comment: Do you have Android 'phones or tablets? Do they register their names in the router? All mine do, but as `Android-XXX...X`, where `XXX...X` is a string of hex digits, not as their normal network names. I would expect the ChromeBook to do the same, but I don't have one to check.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same question. my belief is that, no, chromebooks do not by default have a computer name and thus send the * to the DNS server. others have mentioned they use the code names in the build sometimes (kevin, caroline, terra) as well. it is not clear how/if you can change the machine name